# Recursive FIbonacci arm Assembly

Tags: recursion, assembly, arm, fibonacci

Edit: I have removed my code as I do not want to get caught for cheating on my assignment. I will repost the code once my assignment has been submitted. I apologize for posting it on stack overflow, I just had no where else to go for help. Please respect my edit to remove the code. I have tried deleting it, but it will not let me as I need to request it.

[MIPS code I was trying to follow][1]

[C Code I was trying to follow][2]

I am trying to convert recursive fibonacci code into arm assembly but I am running into issues. When running my arm assembly, the final value of the sum is 5 when it should be 2. It seems as though my code loops but maybe one too many times. Any help would be much appreciated as I am new to this.

Comment: Your use of `R2` is confusing to me, not sure how you want that to work. Use your debugger/simulator to single step the code and see where it deviates from your intentions.

Comment: @Jester I am using R2 as my sum operand as I am not sure where to store the sum. Would you have another way of doing it that is more efficient?

Comment: You are using `R2` as a global variable.  This is ok, unless you're trying to learn how the standard calling convention works: it would provide a return value in `R0` instead.

Comment: It looks like you are not following a usual recursive fib in your assembly.  Are you trying to do the usual or something non-standard?  If non-standard, can you share the C code for this, and, does it work?

Comment: @ErikEidt I added two pictures that I was trying to follow, it seems as though I have translated them wrong. Would you suggest a better way of doing a Fibonacci recursive? If so, how would I go about that

Comment: I would start with a function signature of `int fib ( int n );` and use the standard calling convention: passing `n` in `R0` (and passing nothing else) and function result / return value out in `R0`.  It will have to copy some registers around, and so, I would also disregard efficiency and go for correctness and the use of the standard calling convention & register usage (anyway, recursive fib is not an efficient way of computing no matter what, so this is a really an exercise of learning how we do functions calling functions on ARM).

Comment: The C code is correct.  (I would have forgone the unnecessary `else` keywords.)

Comment: The MIPS version is flawed.  It is saving the argument register, `$a0`, in prologue, and restoring in epilogue (unnecessary for call clobbered registers) instead of restoring it after the 1st call to `fib` and before the 2nd call, when it needs `n` for `fib(n-2)`.  That it works is either by accident or non-standard design as it is not following the MIPS calling convention; it should not be taken as proper example.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code is doing, and below is a test run.  This simply isn't a usual recursive fibonacci.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f ( int );

int R2 = 0;

int main () {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        R2 = 0;
        f ( i );
        printf ( "f ( %d ) = %d\n", i, R2 );
    }
}

void f ( int n ) {
    if ( n == 0 ) { R2 += 0; return; }
    if ( n == 1 ) { R2 += 1; return; }
    f ( n-1 );
    f ( n-2 );
    R2 += n-1;
}

f ( 0 ) = 0
f ( 1 ) = 1
f ( 2 ) = 2
f ( 3 ) = 5
f ( 4 ) = 10
f ( 5 ) = 19
f ( 6 ) = 34
f ( 7 ) = 59
f ( 8 ) = 100
f ( 9 ) = 167
```

Either you started with a broken Fibonacci algorithm, or substantially changed it going to assembly.  I don't know how this can be fixed, except by following a working algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the C code the only addition is in the `fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`. In particular the special cases just do `return 0;` and `return 1;` respectively. Thus your `else add 0/1 to sum` lines are wrong. You should replace your additions with moves.

Also, you do `MOV R1, R0 //copy fib(n-1)`  which is incorrect because the `fib(n-1)` has been returned in `R2` not `R0`. That should be `MOV R1, R2`.

With these changes the code works, even if it is slightly non-standard.